# Join rows having the same ID while keeping some info on certains rows in python

Tags: python, dataframe, join

I have a data frame like this

```
id   Name     Car        Country   Date
1    Pedro   toyota      Mexico    01/01/2020
1    Pedro               Mexico    01/05/2020
2    Jan     Mercedes    France    02/02/2018
2    Jan     KIA                   10/10/2018
2    Jan     Ford                  01/01/2020
3    Tina    Chevrolet   USA       04/05/2020
```

I would like to group rows by id, if in the column I have the same information I keep it, if in one of the columns I don't have anything I keep the last know value and if there are multiple values I keep only the last one (viewing the dates)

At the end I would like to have something like this

```
id   Name     Car        Country   Date
1    Pedro   toyota      Mexico    01/01/2020
2    Jan     Ford        France    01/01/2020
3    Tina    Chevrolet   USA       04/05/2020
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
# Change blank values into NaN
>>> df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
>>> print(df)
     Name        Car Country        Date
id                                      
1   Pedro     toyota  Mexico  01/01/2020
1   Pedro        NaN  Mexico  01/05/2020
2     Jan   Mercedes  France  02/02/2018
2     Jan        KIA     NaN  10/10/2018
2     Jan       Ford     NaN  01/01/2020
3    Tina  Chevrolet     USA  04/05/2020
```

```py
>>> print(df.ffill().groupby('id').last())
     Name        Car Country        Date
id                                      
1   Pedro     toyota  Mexico  01/05/2020
2     Jan       Ford  France  01/01/2020
3    Tina  Chevrolet     USA  04/05/2020
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)